# Db.find get null

Tags: javascript, node.js, react-native, mongoose

We are trying to figure out how get the data from the database but the result get "null"

the model

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const ClubSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nomClub: String,
  classement: String,
  dateMatch: String,
  classementDB: String,
  logo: String,
  adversaire: String,
});
const SportSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  nom: String,
  clubs: [ClubSchema],
});
module.exports = mongoose.model("sport", SportSchema);
```

and the back

```
getSportAdversaire: (req, res) => {
    Sport.findOne({ "clubs.nomClub": "Stade Rennais" }, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.json({ message: "une erreur s'est produite" });
      } else {
        res.json(data);
        console.log(data);
      }
    });
  },
```

Answer (score 1):

You dont need to use the key as `clubs.nomClub`. You can simply use the key as `nomClub`. Your key name is `nomClub` and not `clubs.nomClub`.

```
sport.findOne({ "nomClub": "Stade Rennais" }, (err, data) => {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.json({ message: "une erreur s'est produite" });
  } else {
    res.json(data);
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Same problem, same answer "null" :(

Comment: @Wendy it seems that there is a typo in your Collection name. The first letter S is small cased in defenition  where as capital cased while finding from the collection